# GUI extension problem with IE11

Tags: gui-extensions

We have a GUI extension in Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 which makes a call to a C# extension to retrieve page's minor version URL (if exists) and open the page in a new window. The flow works perfectly fine in Chrome however it doesn't in IE11.

Problem with IE is before I put the page to workflow, if I use the GUI extension to open the page in Staging, and then put the page into workflow and retry the GUI extension, Tridion doesn't call my C# extension to get the minor version page details. Instead it uses the information from cached copy from previous operation.

Any thoughts on how to make IE do a call back to my C# extension will be really helpful?